# Automate the process of atributing an unique ID based on another column value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a database where a column with a default ID of 100 and another column with duplicate values of strings in SQL are stored. Something like this:

```
100                  BEYONDIFUL !
100                  BEYONDIFUL !
100                  BEYONDIFUL !
100                  BEYONDIFUL !
100                  JAGUAR
100                  JAGUAR
100                  JAGUAR
100                  JAGUAR
...
```

And before, when I wanted to update the ID column to an unique ID, I'd do this:

```sql
UPDATE table
    SET dbo.table.Id = '01'
    WHERE dbo.table.Value LIKE 'THE SENIOR'
```

So that it would be like this:

```
01                  BEYONDIFUL !
01                  BEYONDIFUL !
01                  BEYONDIFUL !
01                  BEYONDIFUL !
02                  JAGUAR
02                  JAGUAR
02                  JAGUAR
02                  JAGUAR
...
```

However, this isn't practical with very large databases since it has to be done to every string in the value column.

How can I make this automatic so that, for every unique value (and it's duplicates), it atributes an ID between 01 and n (n = number of distinct values)?

Comment: What is the rule for deciding which string value gets which ID value, and is your ID really a varchar?

Comment: Alphabetical order and yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to generate youe ID values and update like so. Without any clarification of how the numbering should be applied, this just assigns numbers based on alphabetical ordering.

```
update t set t.Id=v.id
from Table t
join (
 select [value], Row_Number() over (order by [value]) Id
 from Table group by [value]
)v on v.[value]=t.[value]
```